# sed giving error when I try to replace a string

Tags: bash, sed

when I try to edit a yaml file, and replace the string after `image :`

I am doing this `sed -i "s/\<image :\>/& bar/" test.yaml`

where my test.yaml file has this

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2019-11-19T22:42:10Z"
  generation: 1
    ....
        image: foo
```

want replace foo with bar

getting error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command 
>   this is the error I am getting

Comment: You're missing an asterisk in your pattern, try  `\<image\> *: `.

Comment: >sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command this is the error I am getting

Comment: remove the forward slash from the beginning near "s"

Answer (score 0):

In sed, you can't put a forwardslash `/` before the substitution command `s`. The correct syntax is `s/regexp/replacement/` or simply `s/old/new/`.

When you execute sed like you did with `sed -i "/s/\<image :\>/& bar/"`, it will expect a builtin command after the second `/` such as `sed -i /regexp/command` or `sed -i /string/d` to delete the line with the matched string. However, it find the \ character and stops because it isn't a sed command.